# Make Avada Top/Secondary Header Sticky

Tags: css, sticky

I would like to make the top/secondary header fixed, but not my entire header or menu, just the top bar. I am having problems getting this to look right and keep the entire bar sticky/fixed. This code moved it to the left of the page and cut off the rest of the bar, keeping only the area with the phone number like in this picture:

http://swift.freshstartmedia.net/

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzzdF.png)

`.fusion-secondary-header {`
    `position:fixed;`
    `top:0px;`
    `left:0px;`
    `z-index:1000;`
`}`

What am I doing wrong? Appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: Hi Danielle, please can you make a [mcve] within the question otherwise it is off topic for this site - see [something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) - sometimes reproducing the code will often help you find the cause of the error

Comment: I have the code in my question

Comment: Please read the first link in my comment above - that is minimal, yes but not verifiable nor complete